# Python lru_cache implementation

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to understand the implementation of `lru_cache` `decorator` in python (3) specifically how it creates the `key` from function `args` for its internal `dict`.

I have been reading this https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/functools.py#L414

I am unable to understand why there is this `kwd_mark = (object(),)` in the function. I see that it is making a `tuple` with only an instance of `object()` and what it seems like is that it is like a delimiter between all of the `args` and `kwargs/kwds` for the `key` for a function call.
I am trying to understand if it is doing anything special here https://repl.it/repls/ExpensiveFinishedSandboxes but I can not think of anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Links are good, but they have a tendency to break, so I'll try to include everything directly in the answer. We have a function like this (simplified):

```
def make_key(args, kwds, kwd_mark = (object(),)):
    key = args
    if kwds:
        key += kwd_mark
        for item in kwds.items():
            key += item
    ...
    return key
```

The comment in there is rather descriptive:

> Make a **cache key** from <...> positional and keyword arguments. The key is constructed in a way that is **flat as possible** rather than as a nested structure that would take more memory.

Let's try a few sample runs:

```
>>> print(make_key((1, 2, 3), dict()))
(1, 2, 3)
>>> print(make_key((1, 2, 3), dict(a='x', b='y')))
(1, 2, 3, <object object at 0x7f6faf99d0c0>, 'a', 'x', 'b', 'y')
>>> print(make_key((1, 2, 4), dict(b='y', a='x')))
(1, 2, 4, <object object at 0x7f6faf99d0c0>, 'b', 'y', 'a', 'x')
```

The result is a hashable tuple that represents the parameters a user has called their `user_function` with. As you noted, `kwd_mark` is used as a *sentinel value* between args and kwargs, so that the following calls are cached separately:

```
user_function(1, 2, 3, 'a', 'x')
user_function(1, 2, 3, a='x')
```

---

We could have used `None` as a delimiter, but what if someone calls a function with `None` as a parameter? While an `object()`, an object of the base class in Python, does not do much on its own, its *unicity* is useful. You cannot confuse a parameter with the delimiter if your delimiter is one-of-a-kind! And since this sentinel is created at the function definition time, it will stay the same through the run of a program (note that the results above refer to the same `<object object at 0x7f6faf99d0c0>`), so its hash will be the same.

You might ask, why not make it `kwd_mark=object()`? I think the reason here is that it is only used to “append” it to a tuple, so otherwise you would have to make a new tuple every time (remember, tuples are immutable):

```
def make_key(args, kwds, kwd_mark=object()):
    key = args
    if kwds:
        key += (kwd_mark, )  # new tuple
        for item in kwds.items():
            key += item
```